# Connect to AWS S3 without API

Tags: amazon-s3

I've looked everywhere on the Interweb but couldn't find a satisfying answer...

Does anybody know what "protocol" the AWS S3 speaks?

Our idea is to write a Function for a PLC (no chance to use the provided API) to communicate directly with AWS S3.

For Example PLC to "AWS IoT" works in MQTT/HTTP - how can I skip "AWS IoT"?

I know there is the possibility to put an IoT device inbetween - but we are evaluating our possibilities right now.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

All of the AWS services have a documented REST API - the S3 one is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html).  In addition, all of their libraries are open source so you could likely get some ideas from them too.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your quick answer - (i'm not a expert in REST API) but I'm pretty sure an PLC like Siemens S7 1500 can't use the REST APi (but I still hope I'm wrong)

Comment: Ultimately it's a socket connection and a bunch of protocol.  I'm definitely not an expert in PLC development - what kind of network or other connectivity would it have?  Would this be better discussed in http://iot.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Davant to clarify this at an extremely high level, S3 speaks a documented, human-readable protocol, that rides over ordinary HTTP(S).  If *any* device has Internet connectivity and libraries can be found or written to enable HTTP(S) and HMAC-SHA256, a capable developer can make it talk to essentially any AWS service, including S3.